# boolean false posted through form_submit instead of values - codeigniter

Tags: php, forms, codeigniter

So I am having trouble with the form_submit in codeigniter,I want to make a form to log in here is the code

**In the autoload.php file i have this**

```
    $autoload['libraries'] = array('database','email','form_validation','MySystem','session');
    $autoload['helper'] = array('form','url');
```

**In the controller auth.php**

```
    class auth extends CI_Controller
       {        
        public function login(){
                    echo 'validation';
        $this->form_validation->set_rules('emaill','email','required|valid_email');
        $this->form_validation->set_rules('passwordd','password','required');
                    $em=$this->input->post('emaill');
                    $ps=$this->input->post('passwordd');
                    var_dump($ps);
                    var_dump($em);
        if($this->form_validation->run() == TRUE){
                        echo validation_errors();
                        $logged=$this->mysystem->login_filtering($em,$ps);
                        if($logged==TRUE){
                            //$this->load->view('login_succses'); }
                            echo 'ssuccses';
                            echo validation_errors();
                            }
                        else {
                            echo 'you don\'nt have an account';
                             }
                    }
                    elseif($this->form_validation->run() == FALSE){
                        echo 'not true';
                        echo validation_errors();}
        }       

}
```

**In the view site.php i have this**

```
     <!-- login -->

<div id="login_form">
  <h4>Already have an account login </h4>
  <h1>Login</h1>
  <?php
    $attr=array('method'=>'POST');
    echo form_open('auth/login',$attr);
    echo form_input('email', 'Email');
    echo form_password('password', 'Password');
    echo form_submit('submit','Login');
    echo form_close();
  ?>
```

**this is what i get**

> validation
>
> boolean false
>
> boolean false
>
> not true
>
> The email field is required.
>
> The password field is required.

I don't know why it does like that , i've tried the same thing with *sign up form* but it's working so what is wrong with my code here

Comment: take a deep breath. now look at the code again - you have misspellings everywhere. 'emaill', 'passwordd', etc

Comment: Oh my God that's right , thanks soo much , maybe i should delete this question cause it's really not good.